# Wipe data in rooted S3

Tags: root-access

I have a rooted Galaxy S3 GT-i9300 with Android 4.3.

I've rooted it using this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gYjoW22h7c
Now, I would like to erase all the data, but don't loose the root access.
Originally, I was going to go to Settings and press Factory Reset, as I used to do before I rooted the device. But then I read in androidcentral that that could "bootloop" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKXTD1-fqbc) my device.

In summary, how can I do to securely wipe all the data (the option called "Factory reset" in Settings) on my rooted S3?

Answer (score 0):

First, turn your Galaxy S3 off. Now, press and hold the Volume Up, Power and Home buttons until you see the Samsung screen. Release the Power button but continue to press Home and Volume Up until you are brought to the stock recovery mode on the Galaxy S3. Of course, if you have installed a custom recovery on the S3 you will be brought here instead.

Now select the wipe data option by going to it using volume up and down and press the home button it'll wipe your phone's data. Now just reboot your galaxy s3 .

Happy trails and don't forget to backup!

Comment: Don't forget that SU may need to be installed again. You also didn't touch on OP's query of bootloop possibility.